# Mock c @PostConstruct

Tags: spring, аннотации

Есть класс A, в котором над одним из методов стоит аннотация @PostConstruct,он инжектится в другой класс B, как правильно сделать мок класса А, что бы в тестах не выполнялся код метода с @PostConstruct? класс B тоже мок.

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример, работающий для последнего Spring Boot + spring-testing + JUnit

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = FileAgentApplication.class)
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class BTest {
@MockBean
private A a;

@Autowired
B b;

@Test
public void test1(){
    Assert.assertNotNull(a);
    Assert.assertNotNull(b);
}

}
```